# Implement the "Total variation distance of probability measures" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, max, distance, distribution

I am trying to implement the [Total variation distance of probability measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) (TVD) in Matlab.
**Would it be correct to use the [max function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), in order to calculate the "supremum" of the TVD equation (here below)?**

[image]

My attempt:

```
% Input
A =[     0.444643925792938         0.258402203856749
         0.224416517055655         0.309641873278237
        0.0730101735487732         0.148209366391185
        0.0825852782764812        0.0848484848484849
        0.0867743865948534        0.0727272727272727
        0.0550568521843208        0.0440771349862259
       0.00718132854578097        0.0121212121212121
       0.00418910831837223        0.0336088154269972
       0.00478755236385398        0.0269972451790634
       0.00359066427289048       0.00110192837465565
       0.00538599640933573       0.00220385674931129
      0.000598444045481747                         0
       0.00299222022740874       0.00165289256198347
                         0                         0
       0.00119688809096349      0.000550964187327824
                         0      0.000550964187327824
       0.00119688809096349      0.000550964187327824
                         0      0.000550964187327824
                         0      0.000550964187327824
      0.000598444045481747                         0
      0.000598444045481747                         0
                         0                         0
                         0      0.000550964187327824
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0      0.000550964187327824
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
                         0                         0
       0.00119688809096349      0.000550964187327824];
P   = A(:,1);
Q   = A(:,2);

% Total variation distance (of probability measures)
d = max(abs(P-Q))
```

Which leads to:

```
d = 0.186241721936189
```

Comment: If your probability measures have a finite set as support (as is necessarily the case with numerical approximations) then yes, a maximum exists and coincides with the supremum. Note also that this site does not support LaTeX. You can generate an image using for example [this online tool](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php) and then insert it in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot @LuisMendo! If you want to write your comment in the Answer section, I will be happy to accept the Answer!

Comment: Done! I didn't post initially because I was suspecting that your problem might be something else, as this seemed rather easy :-)

Comment: Thanks :-) ...Problems do not need to be always difficult and complex.. also with easy things it is always better to be sure, and ask for help from the community :-)

Comment: I just added a note hinting at the diffculties that might arise with non-finite-support distributions. But even in that case `max` applied to the actual data sounds like the way to go

Answer (score 3):

If your probability measures have a finite set as support (as is necessarily the case with numerical approximations) then yes, a maximum exists and coincides with the supremum.

If your finite data is only an *approximation* to the actual, underlying distributions, possibly defined on an *infinite* set, then the maximum of your data will only be an approximation of the actual supremum for the true distributions. Anyway, in that case it would also probably make sense to use the maximum of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The correct Matlab's code would come from a Matlab's user called "Bruno Luong":

```
dFormula = 0.5 * norm(P-Q,1)
```

corresponding to:

[image]
from:
https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1991183-implement-the-total-variation-distance-tvd-in-matlab?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_ques

Comment: I don't understand this. According to your Wiki link in the question, the measure is the supremum (which is the L-infinity norm), not the L-1 norm. How can one be comparable to the other? This makes no sense!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not explain.... the TVD equation with the L1 norm is (should be) equivalent to the TVD equation with the supremum (in my original question)... However, if I understand correctly, the equation I used, i..e ```d = max(abs(P-Q))``` is not correct, and I would use the TVD equation with the L1 norm... Yes, it is not super related to the initial question...but this ```d = 0.5 * norm(P-Q,1)``` implementation would be correct.... if you think these answer and comments are not related to the initial question, please let me know and I will delete them.. :-)

Comment: "the TVD equation with the L1 norm is (should be) equivalent to the TVD equation with the supremum" -- what I'm saying is that no, they're not equivalent. The supremum is the L-infinity norm, which is different from the L-1 norm. Very different. They're the two opposite extremes of the L-n norm. I don't understand how you'd go from the L-infinity norm to the L-1 norm just because the domain is discrete. It makes no sense at all. I'm not saying this answer is not related, it might be the right answer. But I'm saying that the two measures are unrelated, and I'd need to see proof.

Comment: And if I were you, I wouldn't take it for granted that Wikipedia is correct. Read the referenced text, if you have access. Or find some other place where this is shown to be equivalent. Don't assume it's correct just because Wikipedia says so.

Comment: Yes, you are right...!! I will check around some references... :-)

Comment: In the "talk" page for the Wikipedia article, one comment says: *Relation to L1
"When the set is countable, the total variation distance is related to the" -> not only when the set is countable. This characterization (known as Scheffé's identity) also holds in the continuous setting (see. e.g., Theorem 5.1 of Combinatorial Methods in Density Estimation by Luc Devroye, Gabor Lugosi (2001). Clément Canonne (talk) 21:45, 18 February 2019 (UTC)* -- This might very well be correct, some property of probability density functions. But it's weird!

Comment: But anyway, if this relation holds, then either `max(abs())` or `0.5*sum(abs())` would give the same result. Maybe the latter is then less noise sensitive?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835146/414894

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments @CrisLuengo! ...According to math.stackexchange.com/q/3835146/414894, and to my understanding, we have: **(1)** A is a finite set ```A = {1, 2, ..., a}``` defined as ```A = {k : Q(k) > P(k)}``` (and not the matrix ```A``` in my post!),  and **(2)** ```norm(Q-P,1) = sum(abs(Q(k)-P(k)))``` where ```k = 1, 2, ..., a```. Therefore, ```k``` is an index of the set ```A```, indicating when the element ```k``` of distribution ```Q``` is greater than the corresponding element of distribution ```P```.

Comment: Given **(1)** and **(2)**, through the Scheffé's identity (right??), we get **(3)** ```0.5*norm(Q-P,1) = max(Q(A)-P(A))```. Therefore,```0.5*sum(abs(Q(k)-P(k))) = max(Q(A)-P(A))```. As a consequence, what I initially wrote, i.e. ```d = max(abs(Q-P))``` (note: in this comment, I switched Q with P, just to be consistent with the previous comment), would give a different result from ```d = max((Q(A)-P(A))```. Indeed, initially, I did not consider the definition of set ```A```, as, instead, Bruno Luong did in the Matlab forum (see above the link). Do you agree? Do you think this reasoning is  OK?

Comment: I *think* so, yes.